# Why i have 2 type of mesh with tissue addon

Tags: mesh, add-on

With the base mesh and tissue mesh 2 different mesh created. I have this setting for tissue addon

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1s1EjJGsAxSQNts0YwybJeCGC3dal343M)

[image]

This is the result

[image]

The red and green mark are the mesh created by the addon. How the red mark mesh created. Any suggestion or help to have a seamless shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's looks like the patches are rotated randomly, so select active UV in the rotation settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you plz show me screen shot with the above setting what result you have achieved. Hope its the green mark mesh going all the way. Making a seamless mesh.

Comment: @atek i've posted it